# Equivariant maps in the matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

Let $W$ be an irreducible representation of finite group $G$ over complex numbers with degree $n$. By Schur's Lemma, $$\text{End}_G(W^d) \cong Mat_d(\mathbb{C}),$$
where $Mat_d(\mathbb{C})$ is algebra of $d \times d$ matrices over complex numbers.

Suppose $\varphi : \text{End}_G(W^d) \to Mat_d(\mathbb{C})$  be an isomorphism and $\iota:Mat_d(\mathbb{C}) \to Mat_{nd}(\mathbb{C})$ is the injection which sends $A$ to $I_n \otimes A$. The map $\iota \circ \varphi: \tau \mapsto I_n \otimes A$ for some $A \in mat_d(\mathbb{C})$. This means there exists a basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $W^d$ such that all elements of $\text{End}_G(W^d)$ in this basis have the form $I_n \otimes A$ for some $d \times d$ matrices $A$.

How can I rigorously show that elements of $\text{End}_G(W^{d_0})$, where $d_0 < d$, in the basis $\mathcal{B}$ has the form $I_n \otimes A$ for some $d \times d$ matrices $A$ having at most $d_0$ nonzero rows and columns?

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer my question. Please let me know if my answer is correct or not.

Consider $W^d = W_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus W_d$, and let $\pi_i: W^d \to W_i$ and $\eta_i:W_i \to W^d$ be the obvious projection and injection maps, respectively.
Then one can show that $$\theta: \text{End}_G(W^d) \to Mat_d(\text{End}_G(W)),$$ which maps $\tau \mapsto (a_{ij})$ where $a_{ij} = \pi_i \circ \tau \circ \eta_j$, is an isomorphism. For the proof, one can consult Lemma 4.2 in $\textit{A Course in Ring Theory}$ by Passman.

WLOG, consider $W^{d_0}=W_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus W_{d_0}$. So, if $\tau \in \text{End}_G(W^{d_0})$, then $a_{ij}=\pi_i \circ \tau \circ \eta_j$ is zero for $d_0 <i,j \le d$.

Now, since $\text{End}_G(W)$ can be identified with $\mathbb{C}$ by Schur's lemma, we are done.